# Return a value if it is in the range OTHERWISE return another value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 column with a list of countries:

**COLUMN A**

- Afghanistan
- Albania
- Australia
- Bangladesh
- Belgium
- China
- Denmark

**COLUMN B**

- Afghanistan
- Albania
- Bangladesh
- Canada
- China
- Equador

If the value in the Column B exists in the Column C, then I want to display it in the column C.

If the value in the Column B does not exists in the Column C, then I want to display a blank space column C.

The Result should be this one below:

**COLUMN C**

- Afghanistan
- Albania
- blank space
- Bangladesh
- blank space
- China

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),A1,"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]